# Which of these two sentences seems more acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> 1. This worker, to do all of his tasks, is fully able.
> 2. This worker is, to do all of his tasks, fully able.

Comment: Er, did you create a new account or are you not the same user as: http://english.stackexchange.com/users/6346/nicholas-ainsworth

Comment: @Dusty: things happen. Merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use one or the other for some reason unexplained (i.e. rhyme), use the former as it keeps the "is fully able" assembled, and better communicates that essential point; splitting the subject from 'is' seems less significant comparatively.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. Try:

> This worker is fully able to do all of his tasks.

Comment: OK. The example is given as a response to a person who does not think he is able so the sentence is constructed like that to emphasize.

Comment: @nicholas: Constructed to emphasize what?

Comment: In that case, if you are speaking directly to the worker, you could say "You are fully able to do all of your tasks." If you are speaking to someone else who knows the worker, you could say "He is fully able to do all of his tasks."

Comment: to empahsize the fact that he is able to do all of his tasks and not just some of them.

Comment: like you might respond to a claim that nobody likes the president: The president, in the eyes of all the people, is loved. or The president is, in the eyes of all the people, loved.

Comment: You do that by stressing the words as you say them, no need to rearrange the words into an unnatural order:  "This worker is **fully able** to do **all** of his tasks."

Comment: But if the speech is written and not pronounced that is not possible.

Comment: A native English speaker would be more apt to say "The president is loved in the eyes of all people," even in response to a contrary claim.

Comment: If you wanted to emphasize that he is able to do all of his tasks and not just some of them, then include that information as well: "This worker is fully able to do all of his tasks, not just some of them."

Answer (score 0):

Even as a response I would agree that the answer given by HaL is much more appropriate, either of the first two examples seem awkward.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, I'd go with #2.  Making us wait for the verb makes the sentence even more awkward.  That said, HaL's is the most natural.